# Not able to get the value of total records for multiple tabs in one page

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

As per the requirement, I need the value of total records for all tabs data in one page. There are total 6 tabs in one page with different sets of big amount of data -> which has different loading time for different tabs. And to check the loading completing I've used WebDriverWait for the **visibility of Total no. of records which appears when we scroll down to the end of the page.**
[image: Page View with 6 tabs]

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", WebElement-Tab1);
    waitForTotalRecords();
```

After clicking on tab1 then In **waitForTotalRecords() function** following code I'm using:

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", my-WebElemnt)

    String TotalRecords = my-WebElemnt.getText().toString();

    System.out.println("The Total number of records are "+TotalRecords);
```

But it doesn't work and always gives me the total no. of record for 1st tab only

As per my understanding I feel like its because of hidden elemnt because when user clicks on next tab it still refers to 1st tab - total records. and for this I tried this code as well:

```
public String getText(List<WebElement> e)
{
    int size=e.size();
    String Value = "False";

    System.out.println("The size is "+size);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        int x=e.get(i).getLocation().getX();

        if(x!=0)
        {
            String TextValue = e.get(i).getText().toString();

            return TextValue;
        }

    }
    return Value;

}
```

Please suggest how can I get the value of total records for all tabs respectively . 
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

After navigating the to the page, check whether the page is fully loaded or not using the below method

```
 public void pageloadstate() throws InterruptedException {

JavascriptExecutorjs = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

Stringstates =null;

do{

states=js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString();

Thread.sleep(3000);

System.out.println("pageloaded!!!: "+ states);}

while (states== "complete");

System.out.println("pageloaded sucessfully");
```

You can retrieve the data and save , then navigate to other tab and repeat the above.

Comment: It works like charm...Thank you very much.Is there a way to wait for any other element in place of thread.sleep(3000)..?

Comment: because I need to check the loading time for all tabs. thanks

Comment: If you are trying to get the pageload time from UI, it depends on many factors like  Connection Speed, File Types and Sizes,PC Cache.                                                   It would be better if you can check it through postman.